# Texto com background-color e color transparente

Tags: html, css

preciso aplicar um `color: transparent` em um elemento que possui o `background-color: #fff`. Já tentei aplicar um `opacity: 0` mas ele aplica no elemento todo isso, inclusive no background.

meu html atual: `<strong>matar a fome</strong>`

o objetivo é chegar a este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente, por conta da hierarquia, você não vai conseguir a não ser que separe os elementos e posicione posteriormente. Aí você consegue dar esse efeito esperado.

Comment: Pra não perder tempo, joguei uma imagem em .png mesmo. Obrigado da mesma forma!

Comment: Cara, é mais fácil utilizar o rgba, o "a" seria a opacidade, apenas do background. Usa assim: background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse efeito é conhecido como  Knockout Text. Fiz esse modelo pra te ajudar como exemplo. Ele funciona bem no Chrome e FF, Mas no IE fica meio buggado para variar...

Segue o CSS / HTML

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/300/300);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/300/300);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
h1::after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    -webkit-background-clip: initial;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 80%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 data-title="Knockout">Knockout</h1>
</div>
```

Os artigos que usei como referencia são:
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/ e
http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

Comment: boa cara! era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!