# Background de fundo com texto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como eu faço para fazer esse efeito de letras em cima da imagem que está como Background, ou como eu procuro por isso no google?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente isso ainda não é possível. Existe uma pergunta com algo relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255444/8063

Comment: Meu exemplo: https://codepen.io/thecodermarcelo/pen/jZyvdV observe `background-clip` e `text-fill-color`.

Comment: Posso não ter entendido bem sua pergunta. Mas eu acho que dá para para fazer um efeito similar dessa forma. https://codepen.io/BrenoRUCHbr/pen/vdxPOG

Comment: Acha que a resposta dada satisfaz? Pode marcá-la como aceita?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base no comentário do Marcelo Rafael, consegui uma solução para o seu caso.

O suporte é até que interessante, como pode ver [neste link](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-text-fill-color) do Can I Use.

```css
.text {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: url('https://www.screenaustralia.gov.au/sacms/media/samedialibrary/screenguide/titles/tid33797-mountain/tid33797-web/tid33797-mountain-001-hero.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:  center;
  flex-direction: column;
 text-align: justify;
 max-width: 100%;
 }
 span{
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    font-size: 7em;
 }
  p{
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Source Sans', sans-serif;
  }
 body {
 background: url('https://www.screenaustralia.gov.au/sacms/media/samedialibrary/screenguide/titles/tid33797-mountain/tid33797-web/tid33797-mountain-001-hero.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100wh;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

}
.outer-text{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="outer-text">
  <div class="text">
   <span>Stack.</span>
      <p>É divertido ajudar.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Valeu me ajudou

Answer (score 2):

Vou te dar uma solução usando `mix-blend-mode: overlay;` no texto, e dois backgrounds no fundo, um com a imagem, e um com a camada preta com transparência por cima.

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
}

header {
 margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2017/17_04_cat_bg_03.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10vw;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h2 contentEditable role='textbox' aria-multiline='true' >And stay alive</h2>
</header>
```

Comment: Valeu me ajudou